# what does OAT stands for(In ART - Android Runtime)?

Tags: android

This saw 2 more questions related to this

Here is link to previous questions - [What does OAT mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435860/what-does-oat-mean)

[Android compiler, architecture and runtime, how doeas it work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075435/android-compiler-architecture-and-runtime-how-doeas-it-work-together)

so basically I know what is dex2oat tool, and how ART works. I just want to know full form of OAT ?

Comment: How about this comment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254538/difference-between-dexopt-and-dex2oat#comment48198215_26263071

Comment: Also have you watched this Google IO video on ART: https://youtu.be/EBlTzQsUoOw

Comment: As far as my research , I can barely say that OAT stand for --- "Optimized Ahead of Time" .